Does a weather authority rate/measure floods after they happen?
The 100-year flood line runs through my property (Midwest - United States). I am always curious when I see flooding how close to a 100-year flood it might be. Is there any way to know? Does any official service/site post data that rates how significant a flood was? The National Weather Service issues flood warnings. After a significant rainfall, is there a way to know how the flood was rated?

flooding is hydrology not meteorology.

I assume because you mention the National Weather Service that you're interested in the US specifically, or are you interested in other countries?

I am interested in the US only.

I'm not sure whether anyone officially evaluates it (consistently), but here are a few ideas for checking it yourself (for the US, since you mentioned the NWS):

On the precipitation end, you could compare the reported precipitation and duration to the Precipitation Frequency Data Server (PFDS).  For example, during Colorado's 2013 floods, a site in Boulder, CO recorded about 15" of rainfall. That figure was for 7 days, but the description says most of it fell in 30 hours, so we'll say two days.  The PFDS, selecting that point (estimated:  40.0156° N,  -105.2800° E), says that 15" is more than the 1000-year return interval precipitation for a 2-day (or, for that matter, a 7-day) storm.  A 1000-year, 2-day storm would be 9.4".  Therefore, we can say that, in that area, the actual rainfall exceeded a 1000-year storm.
For streamflow, USGS StreamStats can estimate peak flow statistics for a site if you go through the steps for the delineation and report tool, selecting "peak flow statistics", and if you select a gage on the map you can view the "StreamStats Gage Page" with observed flow data (under the "Gage Analysis Plots" tab).  For example, USGS gage 06730200 (on Boulder Creek) had a peak discharge of 8400 cfs during the September 2013 flood.  For estimated floods, StreamStats only goes up to 0.2% (500-year), but that figure is 7420 cfs (generating a report for peak flow statistics).  Thus, the flood was more than a 500-year flood.  Those are estimated values only, but it provides some reference point.


I think streamflow data is probably the only way you can make a direct estimate.  Here's another streamflow gauge data link:  https://water.weather.gov/ahps/index.php
